# Interception of method calls in Application Insights for .Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-application-insights

Is there anyway to have some metric on what methods (not the web request and dependencies) are being called? I can't seem to find anything related to this.

I was looking at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Agent.Intercept ("Enables Interception of method calls") but it seems it's for .NET Framework

Comment: In what kind of scenario you want to know the method being called? In a log file or while debuging? Typically if you want get a report of method called in your application, you can try [Performance Profile Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/?view=vs-2019) to see those metric

Comment: @ElendilZheng-MSFT: Well, I could easily see a scenario where higher level method (which only makes internal calls to other methods and there are no external calls to other services are made). In this situation, I would like to see which internal method is taking too long. Is it possible to configure the AI for .net core to start reporting method to method metrics? is there a flag that we can set for this?

Comment: Ever get an answer to this?

Comment: No, I ended up logging everything and added the namespace to debug output and got the metrics from there